# Combine transduction output with input into a hashmap

Tags: clojure

I want to do the following in Clojure as idiomatically as possible:

1. transduce a collection
2. associate each element of the input collection with the corresponding element in the output collection
3. return the result in a hashmap

Is there a succinct way to do this using core library functions?

If not, what improvements can you suggest to the following implementation?

```clj
(defn to-hash [coll xform]
  (reduce
    merge
    (map
      #(apply hash-map %)
      (mapcat hash-map coll (into [] xform coll)))))
```

Comment: could you please add some input/output examples?

Comment: @leetwinski Consider `(def xform (comp (map inc) (map #(* % %))))`. Running `(to-hash [1 2 3 4 5] xform)` returns `{1 4, 4 25, 3 16, 2 9, 5 36}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this should do the trick without intermediate collections:

```
(defn process [data xform]
  (zipmap data (eduction xform data)))

user> (process [1 2 3] (comp (map inc) (map #(* % %))))
;;=> {1 4, 2 9, 3 16}
```

the docs on [eduction](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eduction) say the following:

> Returns a reducible/iterable application of the transducers
> to the items in coll. Transducers are applied in order as if
> combined with comp. Note that these applications will be
> performed every time reduce/iterator is called.

so no additional collection is created.

This is any good, of course, as long as there is one-to-one relationship between input and output elements. What is desired output for `(process [1 -2 3] (filter pos?))` or `(process [1 1 1 2 2 2] (dedupe))` ?

(by the way, your `to-hash` implementation has the same flaw)

Comment: Indeed, the problem I am solving uses non-filtering transducers. I should have mentioned that in the opening post! Your implementation is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A transducer is a function that takes a reducing function and returns a new reducing function. To make it work with transducers where there is not a one-to-one mapping from elements in the input collection to the output, you will have to use your transducer to create a new reducing function (`step2` in the code below) that will associate elements into your hash map. Something like this.

```
(def ^:dynamic assoc-k nil)

(defn assoc-step [dst x]
  (assoc dst assoc-k x))

(defn to-hash [coll xform]
  (let [step (xform (completing assoc-step))
        step2 (fn [dst x] (binding [assoc-k x] (step dst x)))]
    (reduce step2 {} coll)))
```

This implementation is quite basic and I am not sure to which extent it will work with *stateful* transducers. But it will work with the stateless ones, such as `map` and `filter`.

And we can test it with a transducer that keeps odd elements in the input collection and squares them:

```
(defn square [x] (* x x))

(to-hash (range 10) (comp (filter odd?) (map square)))
;; => {1 1, 3 9, 5 25, 7 49, 9 81}
```